# Globally accessing the main MovieClip

Tags: actionscript-3

**Q**: Is there a way to get the main movieclip (i.e. the entry point of my app) globally? This means: from an object not being an attached movie clip (YES: I know I can access the main movie clip through the ´root´ property parting from an existing movie clip).

What I actually need is to retrieve the movie parameters but I'm using a class which is not related to movieclips at all, so I cannot have access to the standard `root` property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure you can. Just create a static function:

```
//code in the main class:
private static var _main:Main; //assuming your document class is called Main

//set the var in your constructor of Main
public function Main() {
    _main = this;
    //other code
}

public static function getInstance():Main {
    return _main;
}

//code in custom class:
private function doSomething():void {
    var m:Main = Main.getInstance();
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest using an actual getter (`public function get instance():Main{}`) instead. Additionally, and this is directed toward the OP, if you need something like this, you should generally ask yourself *why* you need it. This type of thing specifically goes against basic OOP principles. You should look into passing the object around instead of making a static access point. That said, this answer is exactly what they are asking for.

Comment: Why I needed it: I need to access the movie parameters. Perhaps I'll refactor my code a bit.